# How to do good surface fitting in Mathematica?

Tags: fitting

I would like to fit a 3D surface in Mathematica, and I can do a rough fitting using the following code:

```
pcA = {0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b0 = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.38, 2, 8};
data = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
    0}, {-0.20581267, -0.20537408}, {-84.63568022, -84.67300459}, \
{-693.54120903, -694.76389264}, {-2367.19154818, -2376.5853415}, \
{-5643.98719049, -5683.83259319}, {-11058.7299695, -11180.8973485}, \
{-3.29550886, -3.29616876}, {-1353.7235274, -1356.11078724}, \
{-11081.98696453, -11160.23872496}, {-37758.30515589, \
-38364.78507553}, {-89604.60991136, -92429.58451206}, \
{-173106.62742427, -183772.99571556}, {-42.94292614, -42.9470077}, \
{-17621.5603069, -17733.87089258}, {-143483.98602989, \
-147513.32470484}, {-477118.07034281, -516171.64428457}, \
{-1081773.83443517, -1261385.05922747}, {-1996393.07365274, \
-2506051.02941512}, {-32937.85067656, -32995.82263633}, \
{-11350624.81676851, -14758233.43568452}, {-7.01224627 *10^7, \
-1.06714922 *10^8}, {-1.82968979 *10^8, -2.88464563 *10^8}, \
{-3.44563145 *10^8, -5.43746725 *10^8}, {-5.84905085 *10^8, \
-8.54429559 *10^8}, {-8355905.13266479, -8618891.40387798}, \
{-1.32031130 *10^9, -2.08350129 *10^9}, {-5.76458617 *10^9, \
-8.24301024 *10^9}, {-1.03448406 *10^10, -1.82112091 *10^10}, \
{-1.78326063 *10^10, -3.03581800 *10^10}, {-2.47583344 *10^10, \
-4.28661085 *10^10}
   };
f[n_] := Table[
   Flatten[{Tuples[{b0, pcA}][[i]], data[[i, n]]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[data]}];

surface = 
  Fit[f[2], 
   Level[x + y + (x + y)^2 + (x + y)^3 // Expand, {1}], {x, y}];


Show[ListPlot3D[f[2], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot3D[surface, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

However, the result is not very pleasing:

[image: poor result]

Some critical points, for example, when `b0 = 8`, `pcA` is small, the output is positive, which is not wanted.

But I really do not know how to find very good functions to fit.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be "badly scaled". If I understand you right, you want to get a better approximation near `x,y~0`.  Therefore you could use NonLinearModelFit && Weights:

```
pi = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9}; (*parameters*)
surface =NonlinearModelFit[f[2], {{x, x^2, x^3, y, 2 x y, 3 x^2 y, y^2, 3 x y^2, y^3}.pi }, pi, {x, y}, 
Weights -> Function[{x, y, z}, 1/(x + .001) + 1/y]]
```

The weights force better approximation near x=0 &&y==0

```
Show[ Plot3D[Normal[surface], {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All ], Graphics3D[Point[f[2]]]]
```

[image]